# How to have a field represent the count of related objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a couple of Django models, Channel and Recording.  Channels have a one-to-many relationship with recordings, such that a channel may have many recordings.  Within the Channel model, I currently have 2 fields, num_recordings, and storage_size, which are right now created as Integers, but which I want to have dynamically generated as the result of a DB query. E.g. num_recordings should be the current count of recordings on a given channel, and storage_size should be the sum of a field "size" for each of the recordings on a given channel.

I'm using Django rest framework to give a JSON representation of the models, and want it so that when I query the Channel, I see these two fields as Integers, but don't want to have to calculate these separately, e.g. it would be ideal if when you query the Channel endpoint, it would perform a count on the recording relationship, and return that as "num_recordings" and a sum on the recording.size field for all recordings in the relationship and report that on the storage_size field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach it by benefiting from the `related_name` attribute of `ForeignKey` fields in Django and standard Python `@property` decorator.

---

At first, let's assume that you have defined your relationship in `models.py` like this:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    ...


class Recording(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=..., related_name='recordings')
    # ________________________________________________________________^
    # This is the reverse relation name, e.g. channel.recordings
```

---

From now on, you can access the related `recordings` of a specific `channel` from the `channel` itself:

```
>>> channel = Channel.objects.create(...)

>>> recording1 = Recording.objects.create(channel=channel, ...)
>>> recording2 = Recording.objects.create(channel=channel, ...)

>>> channel.recordings.all()
<QuerySet [<Recording: 1>, <Recording: 2>]>

>>> channel.recordings.count()
2
```

You can use [those methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) in your `Channel` model directly:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def num_of_recordings(self):
        return self.recordings.count()
        # __________^ (related_name)
```

---

Now for your `storage_size`, you can aggregate it via the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) method of `QuerySet` and the [`Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) aggregation function:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


class Channel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def storage_size(self):
        return self.recordings.aggregate(storage_size=Sum('size'))['storage_size']
```

---

And now the final `Channel` model:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def num_of_recordings(self):
        return self.recordings.count()

    @property
    def storage_size(self):
        return self.recordings.aggregate(storage_size=Sum('size'))['storage_size']
```

The last step is to add these new properties `num_of_recordings` and `storage_size` in your *channel serializer class* in order to display them. Since they are decorated with `@property`, they are *read-only* by design and thus are calculated dynamically based on the related recordings.